# Android Data Binding - EditText SetError

Tags: android, validation, android-databinding

We are using the [Kubwa](https://github.com/WesleyElliott/Kubwa) validation library to validate the forms with android data binding library, but the error is not showing in the EditTexts.

**ViewModel:**

```
@Override
public void onLoginClick(View view) {

    validator.validateEmail(user.getEmail());
    validator.validatePassword(user.getPassword());

    notifyChange();

    if (validator.isValid()) connector.login(user);
}

@Bindable
@Override
public String getEmailError() {
    return validator.getEmailErrorMessage();
}

@Bindable
@Override
public String getPasswordError() {
    return validator.getPasswordErrorMessage();
}
```

And my xml:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/email"
android:text="@={viewModel.user.email}"
app:error="@{viewModel.emailError}"/> <!-- As the wiki said -->
```

When I realized that that doesn't work I created a `BindingAdapter` and changed the xml attribute, but it isn't working either.

```
@BindingAdapter("app:errorText")
public static void BindError(EditText view, String error){
    view.setError(error);
}
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you show the `onLoginClick()` binding as well? Perhaps it is not being activated? Are you noticing an error icon next to the edit texts? The documentation says that the pop only shows when the edit text has focus. For a better user experience, you can continuously validate the email and password using two-way data binding. Or, perhaps validate of focus loss instead of on submit.

Comment: I already debugged the onLoginClick(), it does the validations, and I totally agree two way biding or on focus loss would be better, I'm thinking on doing an implementation on that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tried out something similar to your example and it worked fine.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    User user = new User();
    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    binding.setUser(user);
}
```

and the Observable -- I put the validation in the setName, but yours should be the same. You may prefer to have it in the InverseBindingAdapter instead:

```
public class User extends BaseObservable {
    private String name;

    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.example.gmount.tryoutdamnthing.BR.name);
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.example.gmount.tryoutdamnthing.BR.error);
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getError() {
        if (name == null || name.length() < 3) {
            return "Too short!";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and the layout:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable name="user" type="com.example.gmount.tryoutdamnthing.User"/>
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@={user.name}"
                app:error="@{user.error}"
        />

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

My guess is that you didn't use the `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()` or forgot to set the ViewModel object in the binding. Sometimes this happens because people use `Activity.setContentView()` after `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()`.

You can see here that I don't need a BindingAdapter for `app:error` because the setter's name is the same as the attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: I like this answer! Having tried Kubwa I find that it does not are far from finished and thus not flexible enough.

Comment: Should we add setError() method?

Answer (score 2):

This is more a question on how to use the Data Binding library. You're binding `errorText` to the error, but in the layout you use `error`. Changing the BindingAdapter to `@BindingAdapter({"app:error"})` should fix the error

Comment: Try: `@BindingAdapter("error")` as well. Your binding adapter is not setup to match your layout biding correctly

Comment: Could you explain further the second phrase?

Comment: In your layout, you're using `app:error=".."` - so the Data Binding library is binding `error` - however, your BindingAdapter is set to something else (`errorText`).