# MVVM TextInputLayout Validation

Tags: java, android, validation, mvvm, android-textinputlayout

I'm learning MVVM and I want to do the validation of text in the ViewModel layer, not in Fragment.

Data Variables:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewmodel"
        type="com.pup.ccis.mmReady.viewModel.LoginViewModel"/>
    <variable
        name="validator"
        type="com.pup.ccis.mmReady.utilities.validation.validators.UserValidator.Validators" />
</data>
```

Layout XML of TextInputLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_login_til_email"
        style="@style/App_TextInputEditTextStyle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/et_space_0">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            style="@style/App_TextInputEditTextStyle"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Email Address"
            android:autofillHints="emailAddress"
            android:text="@={viewmodel.loginEmail}"
            android:afterTextChanged="@{() -> viewmodel.validate(viewmodel.loginEmail, validator.REQUIRED_FIELD)}"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

The TextInputLayout element has a method setError() that accepts CharSequence. The problem is I cannot bind that as I cannot set it in the Layout XML.
[I have seen this one, but it is a different type of TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37075871/can-i-bind-an-error-message-to-a-textinputlayout/37076057). I have searched everywhere I can.

ViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel extends BaseObservable {
private static final String TAG = "LoginViewModel";

private String loginEmail;
        
@Bindable
public String getLoginEmail() {
    return loginEmail;
}

public void setLoginEmail(String loginEmail) {
    this.loginEmail = loginEmail;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.loginEmail);
}
```

Validate Function in ViewModel:

```
public void validate(String text, Validator validator){
    if(!validator.validate(text)){
        validator.getInvalidMsg(); // Pass this to the TextInputLayout in View Layer so that it will become textInputLayout.setError(validator.getInvalidMsg())
    }
}
```

I know that I can just validate it in the View layer, but if I'm not wrong, Validation of data should happen on the ViewModel layer in MVVM.

Comment: Simply, send the text to your viewmodel -> validate the text -> update mutableLivedata -> observer the livedata in your fragment/activity and update your EditTextError

Comment: @EmmanuelConradie I'm sorry that I forgot to include that my ViewModel extends BaseObservable. I'm using BindingAdapter. How will I achieve it without using MutableLiveData? Thank you.

Comment: I would create a datavariable for your TextInputLayoutError, so that you can notify it if your validate method is false.
Then in your view layer you can check if the error is null or empty and only then do something

Comment: What I mean is link your validator with TextInputLayoutError. Also it's more reliable to use onTextChanged (not after) since onTextChanged is instant. If you don't want to check it constantly you could only check if after (for example) 5 characters

Comment: Why does the answer you linked to not working for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068826/android-data-binding-edittext-seterror
They have already answered your question here.

Comment: Yes, it answered my question. Thank you.